# Content showing on both modal and page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

content should be shown on modal after submitting a form. It is showing too. But when I cancel the modal I can see the content is also showing under modal, specifically where I submitted the form.

Comment: Can you share your code? What modal plugin you are using ? Do you see any console error ?

Comment: you should submit your code too...

Comment: Check that you haven't forget about closing some tags et.c

Comment: Well no console error. I am using boostrap modal. The modal is coming for submitting a form. The form generates from wordpress shortcode

Comment: can you post your shortcode?